Inconsistency in answer, by counting in two different ways
A Committee of 5 members is to be constituted for investigating the cases of money laundering from the group of officers belonging to the Economics Offencer Wings, Anti-Terrorist Squad and Indian Revenue Services. The PMO were given 5 names from EOW; 4 from ATS and 3 names from IRS. In how many ways the team can be constituted when there shall be at least one officer from each group of officers and at most two officers from each group of officers?
(a) 850
(b) 720
(c) 900
(d) None of the above
My approach
Method 1: By Casework of (2,2,1) across three groups, from that i got
$ \left ( {^{5}C_{2} }\times{^{4}C_{2} }\times {^{3}C_{1} }\right)  + \left ( {^{5}C_{2} }\times{^{4}C_{1} }\times {^{3}C_{2} }\right) + \left ( {^{5}C_{1} }\times{^{4}C_{2} }\times {^{3}C_{2} }\right) = 390 $ ways (so, Option D is right)
Method 2: Here first i chose 1 member from each of 3 groups, to remove constraint of atleast one member from each group,in $\left ( {^{5}C_{1} }\times{^{4}C_{1} }\times {^{3}C_{1} }\right)=60$ways but we need committee of 5 so i am still 2 members short. Now, 1 member from each group has already been taken into account in those 60 ways & each group's strength has also been reduced by 1,so, i need to choose 2 members more from remaining people in 3 groups of strength 4,3,2 respectively keeping in mind that i do not choose 2 members from the same group because that would violate atmost 2 condition, so i will choose 1 member from any 2 groups taken at a time in $\left ( {^{4}C_{1} }\times{^{3}C_{1} }+ {^{3}C_{1} }\times{^{2}C_{1} + {^{2}C_{1} }\times{^{4}C_{1} } } \right) =26 $ways. But the confusion arises here now can i say that total ways are $60+26=86$.
Main confusion: In casework it is straightforwardly yielding 390 ways(which most probably is correct), but while solving it intuitively by breaking problem into small parts like first removing each constraint one at a time, getting different answer that way. So, please help me getting answer(or hint) in second way and please tell where am i leaving some large number of cases in second method from which 86 is coming. Thank you in advance

You have made two fundamental errors in the second approach.

[1] Whenever you fractionate selections like that, you are bound to overcount. Suppose you had chosen A from EOW in the first choices you made, you might have included B from EOW in the second round of choices, whereas in another selection, you might choose B in the first round, and A in the second. thus double counting. Just type "fractionate" on this site, and you will get many examples of this fundamental error that people make

[2] You have added the two selection rounds where clearly the multiplicative principle applies. Of course, correcting this won't help, it will only show that such fractionation gives a higher figure due to overcounting.



+1 Yes you are right, i should've multiplied instead of adding. I don't know about 'fractionation' please explain it little bit with some small sample space if possible, infact i am overcounting by factor of 4 i.e., (60*26) divided by 390 = 4. But please point one such case i am unable to see, because i am also reducing group strength by 1 of each group after first round and only then going about second round, but despite that overcounting is occuring which i am unable to grasp. Your explanation was crisp and helpul but please give more hint if possible. Thanks a lot

Just number all the people, (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9), (10,11,12), so round one you might choose 2,6,10 and then 5,9 but you could have selected 5,9,10 in the first round and 2,6 in the second (two persons chosen twice) or  you could have one person chosen twice. So many different overcounts can arise, how can you keep track ? Also, look for more existing answers by searching "fractionate"

Thanks. After searching 'fractionate' with numerous examples, Now i understood it clearly how overcounting due to repeating orders across rounds and not counting in one go is resulting into overcounted total ways.

Glad to be of help ! $;; :)$
